# looping the time with time picker in android

Tags: javascript, java, android, firebase

I am Selecting the time from the picker in android as 2:00

I want to loop the time, like save the values in database as 2 then 3 then 4 and goes on.
How can i achieve this.

This is the code i have so far:

```
Time  = String.valueOf(hourOfDay).toString() + ":" + String.valueOf(minute).toString();
Hour  = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(hourOfDay));
for (DataSnapshot history : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
     MainService = history.getKey();
     Hour = Hour + 1;
     Time = Hour + ":00";
     Log.d("OpDOoesnotexsist", "Create new");
     Log.d("Time hfinal", "Time befoore  is" +Time);
     Log.d("Hour hfinal", "Hour befoore  is" +Hour);
     Log.d("Hour hfinal", "Main Service for no Op is" +MainService);
     Log.d("Time here is", "Hour is" +Time);
     DatabaseReference CreateOp=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Op").child(NameofSpa).child(SELETEDDATE).child(MainService).child(String.valueOf(Time));

     CreateOp.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
         @Override
         public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
         Map userInfo = new HashMap();
         userInfo.put("Count", 1);
         CreateOp.updateChildren(userInfo);
          }
          @Override
          public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
          }
     });
}
Log.d("Time ", "Time here is final" +Time);
```

when i select 2, It starts  with 3 then 4 and goes on. and saving it also from 3 not from 2.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to save the TIME as is (2 in your example) and AFTER SAVE add 1 hour, so the next iterarion will have the correct value.

Comment: What if we have to take the current time from the time picker it varies when the user selects the time. @DanielMiranda

Comment: Well, just obtain the HOUR from the datepicker as a variable and it will take it from there. Just remember that there's just 24 hours a day